# Python problem with lambda/selenium/geckodriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, tkinter

I'm having problems with lambda on webdriver.firefox, when i click on button to start the firefox i got that error:
(the program is suposed to add a login screen to get the login, passowrd and a link that will be used later to log in on a website, but when i click on button to start the geckodriver it's just dont start

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/igBot/igBot.py", line 54, in <lambda>
    ttk.Button(master, text="Login", command=lambda: self.prituserpasswd()).grid(column=1, row=0)
  File "C:/igBot/igBot.py", line 93, in prituserpasswd
    self.login()
  File "C:/igBot/igBot.py", line 58, in login
    driver.get("https://playerlink.gg/login")
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get'
```

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time


class Bot(object):
    def __init__(self, master):

        # Variavéis criada no escopo da classe
        self.username = StringVar()
        self.password = StringVar()
        self.discord = StringVar()
        self.comentario = "  ℍℝ \n \n 0000 \n 00 \n ℂ0ℂℍℕ \n ℂℕ$ Uℝ: 5,5 R$ \n \n DISCOR: \n", self.discord
        self.s = Service(".\driver\geckodriver.exe")
        self.driver = lambda x: webdriver.Firefox(service=self.s)


        # Criação de um frame para o login
        loginFrame = ttk.Frame(master, padding=10)
        loginFrame.grid()

        # Criação da label e input do texto do login (Entry)
        self.labelUsername = Label(loginFrame, bg='#CCCCCC')
        self.labelUsername["text"] = "Usuário"
        self.labelUsername.pack()
        # o texto digitado será armazenado na textvariable e quem recebe é sua variavale global
        self.textoUsername = Entry(loginFrame, textvariable=self.username)
        self.textoUsername.pack()
        self.textoUsername.bind("<Return>", lambda x: self.username)

        # Criação da label e input do texto do password (Entry)
        self.labelPassword = Label(loginFrame, bg='#CCCCCC')
        self.labelPassword["text"] = "Senha"
        self.labelPassword.pack()
        # o texto digitado será armazenado na textvariable e quem recebe é sua variavale global
        self.textoPassword = Entry(loginFrame, textvariable=self.password)
        self.textoPassword.pack()
        self.textoPassword.bind("<Return>", lambda x: self.password)

        # Criação da label e input do texto do discord (Entry)
        self.labelDiscord = Label(loginFrame, bg='#CCCCCC')
        self.labelDiscord["text"] = "Link Discord"
        self.labelDiscord.pack()
        # o texto digitado será armazenado na textvariable e quem recebe é sua variavale global
        self.textoDiscord = Entry(loginFrame, textvariable=self.discord)
        self.textoDiscord.pack()
        self.textoDiscord.bind("<Return>", lambda x: self.discord)

        # você pode passar por parametro também, aqui eu coloquei direto, sem parametro
        ttk.Button(master, text="Login", command=lambda: self.prituserpasswd()).grid(column=1, row=0)

        def login(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://playerlink.gg/login")
        time.sleep(3)
        campo_usuario = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='email']")
        campo_usuario.click()
        campo_usuario.clear()
        campo_usuario.send_keys(self.username)
        campo_senha = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='password']")
        campo_senha.click()
        campo_senha.clear()
        campo_senha.send_keys(self.password)
        campo_senha.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(15)
        self.comentar()

    def comentar(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://playerlink.gg/network")
        time.sleep(5)
        link = ""
        while True:
            campo_comentario = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[class='mb-4']")
            perfil = campo_comentario.find_element_by_css_selector("a")
            linkPerfil = perfil.get_attribute("href")
            if link != linkPerfil:
                post = campo_comentario.find_element_by_css_selector("textarea")
                post.send_keys(self.comentario)
                post.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
                link = linkPerfil

            time.sleep(0.01)

    def prituserpasswd(self):
        print('Usuário: ', self.username.get())
        print('Senha: ', self.password.get())
        print('Discord: ', self.discord.get())
        self.login()


root = Tk()
root.title('Print usuário e senha')
Bot(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: it seems that `loginSite` is a tuple, did you print out what `loginSite` is?

Comment: you can [edit] your question, add the code there, also from what I see then `loginSite` is a tuple and you can't use `.login()` on a tuple

Comment: you can see code now?

Comment: yes and as I told you can't do `loginSite.login()` because `loginSite` is a tuple and tuples don't have such a method (I hope that you at least understand what a tuple is because those are Python very basics)

Comment: i added all the code what it suposed to do

Comment: we don't need the whole code, just a [mre], well I don't know what you are trying to achieve so I can't tell what exactly you should do besides I don't know much about selenium. Either how you can't do `loginSite.login()`

Comment: it's just suposed get self. username and self.password , call the login page and paste login and password

Comment: I think you need to pass `loginSite` as an argument to some function

Comment: i made it work but now i get this new error

Comment: `driver` (i.e. `self.driver`) inside `login()` is a lambda defined inside `__init_()`.

Comment: i put a lamba because it started firefox on start not on button click

Comment: but now it doesn't seems to work with that lambda

Comment: How can you call `driver.get()` if `driver` is a lambda?

Comment: i just made a lambda because it is starting when i run the program instead when i click on button